# How to run HTML Selenium test from node or Python WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use ghost inspector chrome extension to create tests, but it is impossible to run them because website is not online and uses https, with which ngrok don't want to work properly. I find there option to export tests to Selenium format, and it gives me HTML like this:

```
<meta name="ghost-inspector-screenshotCompareThreshold" content="0.1" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">Registration</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>css=a[href="#/registration"]</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>css=a[href="#/registration"]</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
```

How to run test from that file? What I need to install and execute?

Answer (score 2):

[Ghost Inspector](https://ghostinspector.com/) founder here. Those Selenium HTML exports are designed to work with [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) and [Selenium Builder](http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/), both of which are free Firefox extensions. They'll allow you to run your tests locally in your own browser.

If you're interested in turning those tests into code, I'd recommend Selenium Builder above. It has some nice options for importing the HTML provided, then outputting WebDriver code using various different frameworks.

Depending on how complicated your tests are, you may need to do a little bit of tweaking once you import into one of the extensions above, but the vast majority of commands should work out of the box.

Hope that's helpful to you!

Comment: Well, selenium IDE does not allow me to override base URL for testing, and I didn't found where Selenium builder could export cases. But if you know Ghost Inspector better, may be I'm using it wrong?

Comment: Selenium IDE should have a "Base URL" field at the top of it's window. You can see it in the screenshot on the right side, if you follow the Selenium IDE link above. To convert a test using Selenium Builder, open the Selenium Builder extension then choose "File" > "Open a suite or script". Select the HTML file that you downloaded from Ghost Inspector, then choose "File" > "Export..." and you'll get a number of different export formats.